# VBA code in excel 2019 freezing for extended periods, resulting in crash

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

let me preface this by saying I'm very new to VBA coding, and I put together VBA Macro that compares two data sets and looks for matches in a specific column of both tables. The matches aren't on the saw rows, so I had to use loops to search through and identify matches. I then want it to transpose specific information from the information on the matching rows to a new sheet. The code is as follows:

```
Sub TransposeMatchedDataWithArray()
    'Declare variables for the worksheets
    Dim wsFormula As Worksheet, wsFormula2 As Worksheet, wsFormula3 As Worksheet
    'Set the variables to the corresponding worksheets
    Set wsFormula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formula")
    Set wsFormula2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formula2")
    Set wsFormula3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formula3")
    'Declare variables for the named ranges
    Dim rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range
    'Set the variables to the corresponding named ranges
    Set rngStart = wsFormula.Range("Start_Date_Table")
    Set rngEnd = wsFormula2.Range("End_Date_Table")
    'Clear the data in Formula3
    wsFormula3.Cells.Clear
    'Add the headings in Formula3
    wsFormula3.Range("A1").Value = "Start_Date"
    wsFormula3.Range("B1").Value = "AGLC SKU"
    wsFormula3.Range("C1").Value = "Format"
    wsFormula3.Range("D1").Value = "Subcategory"
    wsFormula3.Range("E1").Value = "Company Name"
    wsFormula3.Range("F1").Value = "Brand Name"
    wsFormula3.Range("G1").Value = "SKU DESCRIPTION"
    wsFormula3.Range("H1").Value = "Available Cases"
    wsFormula3.Range("I1").Value = "Case Cost (w/s)"
    wsFormula3.Range("J1").Value = "Case Value $"
    wsFormula3.Range("K1").Value = "End_Date"
    wsFormula3.Range("L1").Value = "Available Cases"
    wsFormula3.Range("M1").Value = "Case Cost (w/s)"
    wsFormula3.Range("N1").Value = "Case Value $"
    'Declare an array to hold the data from the Start_Date_Table
    Dim startArray As Variant
    'Fill the array with the data from the Start_Date_Table
    startArray = rngStart.Value
    'Declare an array to hold the data from the End_Date_Table
    Dim endArray As Variant
    'Fill the array with the data from the End_Date_Table
    endArray = rngEnd.Value
    'Declare a variable for the current row in Formula3
    Dim currentRow As Long
    currentRow = 2
    'Iterate through the rows in the startArray
    For i = 2 To UBound(startArray, 1)
        'Iterate through the rows in the endArray
        For j = 2 To UBound(endArray, 1)
            'Check if the AGLC SKU in the current rows of the startArray and endArray match
            If startArray(i, 2) = endArray(j, 2) Then
'Write the data from the startArray to the current row of Formula3
                wsFormula3.Range("A" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 1)
                wsFormula3.Range("B" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 2)
                wsFormula3.Range("C" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 3)
                wsFormula3.Range("D" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 4)
                wsFormula3.Range("E" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 5)
                wsFormula3.Range("F" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 6)
                wsFormula3.Range("G" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 7)
                wsFormula3.Range("H" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 8)
                wsFormula3.Range("I" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 9)
                wsFormula3.Range("J" & currentRow).Value = startArray(i, 10)
                wsFormula3.Range("K" & currentRow).Value = endArray(j, 1)
                wsFormula3.Range("L" & currentRow).Value = endArray(j, 8)
                wsFormula3.Range("M" & currentRow).Value = endArray(j, 9)
                wsFormula3.Range("N" & currentRow).Value = endArray(j, 10)
                'Increment the currentRow variable
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

There is a lot of data being seached through so I expected it would be slow or may freeze, but it freezes for 30 minutes before ultimately crashing without completion. Is there something I'm missing that could prevent the code from crashing?

I've tried modifying the code to speed it up by disabling screen refreshing, but the results didn't change. That was the only thing I could think of that might work, but it didn't seem to resolve anything.

Comment: But your code works? Because it is strange your arrays are two dimensional as I know, you also need to declare them

Comment: It worked until I expanded the tables where it's pulling the data from where expanded to operate with a larger amount of information

Comment: Hi @GregP, did you get a chance to try the code I posted?

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs slowly because you do many expensive write operations in the inner loop of a nested loop.

I tried rewriting your code in a way that should make it exponentially faster, please let me know if it works or if you get any errors as I can't test it myself right now.

```vb
Sub TransposeMatchedDataWithArray()
    'Declare variables for the worksheets
    Dim wsFormula As Worksheet, wsFormula2 As Worksheet, wsFormula3 As Worksheet
    'Set the variables to the corresponding worksheets
    Set wsFormula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formula")
    Set wsFormula2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formula2")
    Set wsFormula3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formula3")
    'Declare variables for the named ranges
    Dim rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range
    'Set the variables to the corresponding named ranges
    Set rngStart = wsFormula.Range("Start_Date_Table")
    Set rngEnd = wsFormula2.Range("End_Date_Table")
    'Clear the data in Formula3
    wsFormula3.Cells.Clear
    'Add the headings in Formula3
    wsFormula3.Range("A1").Value = "Start_Date"
    wsFormula3.Range("B1").Value = "AGLC SKU"
    wsFormula3.Range("C1").Value = "Format"
    wsFormula3.Range("D1").Value = "Subcategory"
    wsFormula3.Range("E1").Value = "Company Name"
    wsFormula3.Range("F1").Value = "Brand Name"
    wsFormula3.Range("G1").Value = "SKU DESCRIPTION"
    wsFormula3.Range("H1").Value = "Available Cases"
    wsFormula3.Range("I1").Value = "Case Cost (w/s)"
    wsFormula3.Range("J1").Value = "Case Value $"
    wsFormula3.Range("K1").Value = "End_Date"
    wsFormula3.Range("L1").Value = "Available Cases"
    wsFormula3.Range("M1").Value = "Case Cost (w/s)"
    wsFormula3.Range("N1").Value = "Case Value $"
    'Declare an array to hold the data from the Start_Date_Table
    Dim startArray As Variant
    'Fill the array with the data from the Start_Date_Table
    startArray = rngStart.Value
    'Declare an array to hold the data from the End_Date_Table
    Dim endArray As Variant
    'Fill the array with the data from the End_Date_Table
    endArray = rngEnd.Value
    'Declare a variable for the current row in Formula3
    Dim currentRow As Long
    currentRow = 2
    
    Dim startDictSkuToRows As Object
    Set startDictSkuToRows = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sku As Variant, rowColl As Collection
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(startArray, 1)
        sku = startArray(i, 2)
        If Not startDictSkuToRows.Exists(sku) Then
            Set rowColl = New Collection
            rowColl.Add i
            startDictSkuToRows.Add Key:=sku, item:=rowColl
        Else
            startDictSkuToRows(sku).Add i
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim resultColl As Object, row As Variant, vItem As Variant
    Set resultColl = New Collection
    For j = 2 To UBound(endArray, 1)
        'Check if the AGLC SKU in the current rows of the startArray and endArray match
        If startDictSkuToRows.Exists(endArray(j, 2)) Then
            For Each row In startDictSkuToRows(endArray(j, 2))
                resultColl.Add VBA.Array(startArray(row, 1), _
                                         startArray(row, 2), _
                                         startArray(row, 3), _
                                         startArray(row, 4), _
                                         startArray(row, 5), _
                                         startArray(row, 6), _
                                         startArray(row, 7), _
                                         startArray(row, 8), _
                                         startArray(row, 9), _
                                         startArray(row, 10), _
                                         endArray(j, 1), _
                                         endArray(j, 8), _
                                         endArray(j, 9), _
                                         endArray(j, 10))
            Next row
        End If
    Next j
    
    'Convert collection to array
    Dim resultArray As Variant
    ReDim resultArray(0 To resultColl.Count - 1, 0 To 13)
    i = 0: j = 0
    For Each row In resultColl
        For Each vItem In row
            resultArray(i, j) = vItem(j)
            j = j + 1
        Next vItem
        j = 0
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    wsFormula3.Range("A2").Resize(resultColl.Count, 14).Value = resultArray
End Sub
```

Comment: is `vba.array` creating an array

Comment: @xlmaster yes, it it creates an array. It's also possible to use just `Array` instead but `VBA.Array` ensures that the array is always 0 based even if `Option Base 1` is defined inside the module. This is why I use `VBA.Array` here, since I later assume the created array is 0 based.